# HTML: Does text need a container element conform to standards?

Tags: html, standards, w3c, semantic-markup

Is the following W3C Compliant:

```
<div>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  This is the text for this section.
</div>
```

Or does the text require a container element?

```
<div>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>This is the text for this section.</p>
</div>
```

The first example doesn't sit right with me, but a content editor asked me and I realized I don't really know if it's okay.

Comment: What did your [HTML validation tool](https://validator.w3.org) say?

Comment: Fair point, it says it's valid. I still don't think I like it, though.

Comment: Technically they are both valid. Speaking from experience, your markup is made way more maintainable by putting all text inside some type of lower level container like a `paragraph` or `div`. Your fellow developers (and designers) will appreciate it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Both examples are valid.**

Technically in the first one, the text ***is*** inside a container, the outer `<div>`.

Anyway it is perfectly valid to put text directly inside the [`<body>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#elementdef-body), which means the following HTML document will pass [validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) with no errors or warnings:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    This is the text for this section.
</body>
</html>
```

The more relevant question is whether it is [semantically correct](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#elements-semantics). To put it simply, paragraph text should be surronded by a `<p>` tag. More generally each type of content SHOULD be written inside the semantically relevant tag.

Comment: The two markups are not only valid, under HTML5 rules, they're semantically identical. The un-`<p>` tagged text is still a [Paragraph](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#paragraph) exactly the same as when it's wrapped in `<p>` tags.

Comment: However it is not a paragraph ***element*** that you can individually target, style, manipulate... So wrapping content in the proper tag has many advantages, and don't forget search engines.

Answer (score 1):

I will advise you to use the second approach.
When you use the correct Heading Tag it helps boost your page SEO wise. 
Moreover, paragraph tag, P, helps some browser to render your page in “reading mode”. 
Finally, a div is a block-displayed element. This CSS code looks a bit weird: `div {color: blue}`. But, `p { color: red; }` make more sense for a lot people.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, both are conforming HTML (unless you validate it against the strict HTML4.x/XHTML1.x scheme which [has no connection to reality anymore](https://friendlybit.com/html/html5-is-not-an-option/)). Hovewer, the second approach would be probably more convenient from the styling/scripting perspective, where it's always better to have a possibility to address any piece of content directly. The first example has an [implicit paragraph](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#paragraphs), and explicit is usually better than implicit.